# changing system of turtlebot from indigo to kinetic

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to change the system  of the robot from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

can I change?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311606/changing--system-of-turtlebot-from-indigo-to-kinetic/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just have changed from ros indigo to kinetic, you can install turtlebot package for kinetic using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot
```

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-01-06**:
thank you so much